# How to calculate this special determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{{a_1} + a_1^{ - 1}}& \cdots &{a_1^{n - 1} + a_1^{n - 3} + a_1^{n - 5} +  \cdots  + a_1^{1 - n}}\\
1&{{a_2} + a_2^{ - 1}}& \cdots &{a_2^{n - 1} + a_2^{n - 3} + a_2^{n - 5} +  \cdots  + a_2^{1 - n}}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1&{{a_n} + a_n^{ - 1}}& \cdots &{a_n^{n - 1} + a_n^{n - 3} + a_n^{n - 5} +  \cdots  + a_n^{1 - n}}
\end{array}} \right|$$

How to calculate it? Is it possible to transform it into Vandermonde?

I want to know whether it can never be zero if $a_i\ne a_j$.
Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Notice for any $k > 0$, $a^k + a^{k-2} + \cdots + a^{2-k} + a^{-k} = P(a + a^{-1})$ for some monic polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $k$. So the determinant is equivalent to a Vandermonde determinant with entries $(a_i+a_i^{-1})^{j-1}$

Comment: Get it! Thank you so much!